# DatagridViewButtonColumn with different Text and different Functionality for different Rows

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

I need to create a datagidview in winforms. It has a Datagridviewbuttoncolumn and few other columns. The Datagridviewbuttoncolumn must intially display text "Upload" and clicking on it should open a location to store files. After file is uploaded the Datagridviewbuttoncolumn text should become "View File" and clicking on it should open the file. A brief idea how it could be done will be helpful.

[image: A snapshot of how it should look]

Comment: What is your effort?

Comment: Can you show some code of what you tried ?

Comment: To render different text, handle [`CellFormatting`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting(v=vs.110).aspx) event and set `e.value` based on your logic. To run different functions when the user click on cell, handle [`CellContentClick`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellcontentclick(v=vs.110).aspx) and check what the function you want run.

Answer (score 2):

**Different Text for Buttons**

- Handle [`CellFormatting`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting(v=vs.110).aspx) event and set `e.Value` based on value of other columns or any other logic you need.

**Different Functionality for Buttons**

- Handle [`CellContentClick`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellcontentclick(v=vs.110).aspx) and decide about the task that you want to run based on value of other columns or any other logic you need.

**In both events**

- First check if the event is fired for a data cell, not a header cell, check `e.ColumnIndex` and `e.RowIndex` should be greater than `-1`
- Then check if the event is fired for your desired column, for example to check if the event is for column at index `0`, `e.ColumnIndex` should be equals to `0`
- To get value of another column in the same row, for example column at index 2, simply use `dataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(2).Value`. So you can decide about the text or about the code you want to run, based on value of other columns.

Comment: It seems the post answers your question, let me know if you have any problem applying the solution or if you find it useful :)